# Mongodb query to node.js format

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
db.gpsvalues.aggregate([
  {$sort:{"Timestamp":1}},
  {$group:{
    "_id":"$EmpID",
    LastUpdated:{$last:"$Timestamp"},
    Latitude:{$last:"$Latitude"},
    Longitude:{$last:"$Longitude"}
  }}
])
```

this is the query which returns expected value in mongodb. but i want to get the same values from node.js api call?
can someone tell me how to make the node.js api?
thanks in advance

Comment: try this tutorial http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/10/01/creating-a-restful-api-tutorial-with-nodejs-and-mongodb/.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the [mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) node.js client which supports aggregation as mentionned in the [manual](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs#collection). 
I personnally have not used this feature yet but it should work as expected.